# cURL does weird things with cookies

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I'm trying to manage an account on external site through cURL, however cURL code I am using does weird things. I login through login.php and try to access the account through account.php.

This is part of code in login.php:

```
$cookieFile = $functions->random(10, 1); //function generates random file name
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://strona.com/login.php");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "login=user&password=password");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);        
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,             $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/web/cookies/'.$cookieFile.'.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/web/cookies/'.$cookieFile.'.txt');
$getCookie = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$cookieContainer =         file_get_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/web/cookies/'.$cookieFile.'.txt');
$cookieIdPos = strpos($cookieContainer, "JSESSIONID");
$setFinalCookie = "JSESSIONID=".substr($cookieContainer, ($cookieIdPos+11), (strlen($cookieContainer)-1));
$setExpireDate = (time() + 1500);
```

Upon executing the code, it's created and written properly. This is how an example cookie looks like:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# [url="http://curlm.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html"]http://curlm.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html[/url]
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

strona.com  FALSE   /   FALSE   1405347742  md5 1389795742074
strona.com  FALSE   /   FALSE   0   JSESSIONID  0F6BCB6D89F2DCD2B3B77AAA33AEA69A
```

Example headers upon login are as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found Date: Wed, 15 Jan 2014 14:37:09 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Set-    Cookie: JSESSIONID=BDC17E49CAE16F876D22BE97C155E573; Path=/; HttpOnly Location: [url="http://strona.com/login.php;jsessionid=BDC17E49CAE16F876D22BE97C155E573"]http://strona.com/login.php;jsessionid=BDC...D22BE97C155E573[/url] Content-Language: en-US Vary: Accept-Encoding Content-Encoding: gzip Content-Length: 20 Connection: close Content-Type: text/html HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Wed, 15 Jan 2014 14:37:09 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Content-Language: en-US Vary: Accept-Encoding Content-Encoding: gzip Content-Length: 21445 Connection: close Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
```

It's working up to this point. Now, with account.php code:

```
$cookie = $functions->get_cookie(); //gets previously generated (not included in the code above) and saved cookie and cookie file name
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://strona.com/account.php");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie["cookie"]);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,     $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/web/cookies/'.$cookie["cookiefile"].'.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/web/cookies/'.$cookie["cookiefile"].'.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
$curlData = curl_exec ( $curl );
echo $curlData;
```

This should display a normal account page, shouldn't it? Well, it doesn't. Webpage responses with "You are not logged in" and returns this cookie:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# [url="http://curlm.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html"]http://curlm.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html[/url]
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

strona.com  FALSE   /   FALSE   1405347742  md5 1389795742074
```

The case is:

- cookie is fetched correctly,
- cookie is saved in a file correctly with proper chmod set,
- cookie is saved in the database properly,
- cookie is fetched in $cookie["cookie"] properly,

and yet, when used for accessing the page that requires me to be logged, it doesn't work.

login.php logs me in successfuly, account.php says I'm not logged in.

What's the case?

Help, anybody!

Answer (score 0):

Remove these two lines from your code so that it can load the Session Cookies also from the cookie file. Currently it doesn't allow you to load the session cookies from the cookie file.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie["cookie"]);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "return"? Should I remove these lines from account.php?

Comment: Typing mistake. It should be `Remove`.

Comment: It doesn't work : (

This is cookie file:

`# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
    # http://curlm.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
    # This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

    strona.com FALSE / FALSE 1405363555 md5 1389811555762
    strona.com FALSE / FALSE 0 JSESSIONID 2E7FB34A8333BE2A7B4DCD5E715AB661`

And these are the headers responded to that exact cookie file:

Comment: ``HTTP/1.1 302 Found Date: Wed, 15 Jan 2014 18:45:59 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Location: http://strona.com/notLoggedIn.html Content-Language: en-US Vary: Accept-Encoding Content-Encoding: gzip Content-Length: 20 Connection: close Content-Type: text/html HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Wed, 15 Jan 2014 18:46:00 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Content-Language: en-US Vary: Accept-Encoding Content-Encoding: gzip Content-Length: 5717 Connection: close Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8``

Comment: Run the script enabling the verbose mode. It will help you to observe the cookie that is sent during http request. `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);`

Comment: This is AFTER login.php (successful login)

http://pastebin.com/FNC8ScVC

And this is AFTER calling account.php (where I'm not logged in when I should be)

http://pastebin.com/urCDZRtC